# iOS Charts: Where are the values actually coming from?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have the following Xaxis formatter:

```
extension ChartXAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        guard let referenceTimeInterval = referenceTimeInterval,
        let selectedFrame = selectedFrame
        else {
            return ""
        }
        
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value * 3600 * 24 + referenceTimeInterval)
        
        if(selectedFrame == .week) {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E"
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date).capitalized
        }
        else if(selectedFrame == .month) {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date).capitalized
        }
        else {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date).capitalized
        }
    }

}
```

And I call it like so: `xAxis.valueFormatter = ChartXAxisFormatter(referenceTimeInterval: referenceTimeInterval, selectedFrame: selectedFrame)`

However, this is just formatting the values, it isn't actually deciding what values appear in the xAxis.

When I run it, I get something like: 5 5 6 6 6 7

I can fix this by setting `xAxis.granularity = 1` but I get 5 6 without the 7.

What is actually deciding what values appear? How can I get just the unique values?

For example if I had access to what values it uses I can call something like `Array(Set(array))`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `XAxisRenderer` in the Charts library. It has a `computeAxisValues` function that actually calculates the values that appear on the axis. The `entries` array of the axis stores the values that will be displayed.

If you want to format it, you'll have to subclass the XAxisRenderer and override the `computeAxisValues` function